# Javascript file not loading in Chrome, but loading in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

main.js file not loading in Chrome, but work in Firefox.

Comment: Is there anything showing up in developer console? Also check for cases in the file name.

Comment: src="javascripts/main.js"

Comment: i think its blocked , is there a yellow notification bar below of page when load it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing src link to src="./javascripts/main.js" or src="javascripts/main.js"